# how to send email in php from localhost?

Tags: php

I am unable to send email from localhost using php script
this is my code

```
<?php

ini_set("SMTP","bhoi@gmail.com");

ini_set("smtp_port","25");

ini_set('sendmail_from', 'bhoi@gmail.com');

//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'deepan@gmail.com';

//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 

//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 

//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: bhoi@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: bhoi@gmail.com";

//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 

echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

?>

php.ini file...

[mail function]

; For Win32 only.

SMTP = localhost

smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.

sendmail_from =bhoi@gmail.com

the out put is "Mail failed"

please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: I doubt `bhoi.test@gmail` is a smtp server

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you the easiest way.

You can use open-source [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut) and download the application and run it without any change in the xampp `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` files. Then when you run your mail in php you will directly get it into papercut application.This is application is awesome and you don’t have to configure anything.

Note: Please don’t make any change in xampp like changing `smtp_server`.Just keep the default xampp settings .

Answer (score 1):

you need to install smtp server or set config for public mail servers

look this for example

```
SMTP = smtp.yourdomain.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@yourdomain.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = info@yourdomain.com
```

Comment: how to set config for public mail server ?

Comment: look this [mail function]
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
username = info@Mmydomainname.com
password = myemailpassword
sendmail_from = info@mydomainname.com
Alternatively you can do:

<?php
ini_set( 'smtp_port', 465 );

Answer (score 0):

I tried fake sendmail for windows and it worked for me. you can check it out here.
http://glob.com.au/sendmail/
After than you have to set sendmail_path in php.ini to the path of the sendmail path on your hard drive.